# Some kind of stringing

Tags: stringing, anycubic-kobra-max

I experience some lines on my prints. However, I would not really call them "stringing".

I have seen some stringing and it was rather like an undefined spider web.

But the lines that you see in my photo are super straight and fine.

Are they called "stringing" too? And how do I get rid of them?

Specs:

- Printer: Kobra Max
- Nozzle: 200 °C
- Bed: 50 °C
- Filament: GiantArm PLA

[image: Photo of print bed with faint filament lines that don't look like part of the printed model]

Comment: This is not stringing, this is oozing of material during travel move. Maybe you should change the title to "Unwanted deposited lines on build plate!". Retraction and combing are the options in the slicer you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

They're caused by filament being pulled during travel so they qualify as stringing.

You need to look at your retraction and heat, speed as well makes a difference. You can try combing and other things or just pull them off.

Comment: Do you think I should lower or raise the speed?

Comment: I think you should just pull the string off.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide a better picture, i.e. a finished print.

Stringing is generally something you don't worry about - adjust your retraction settings a tiny bit to retract more.
I didn't see what software you used, that will help with where the settings are.

Also the plate is very different from the rest of the layers, it could just be a leveling issue.